# All session expire after logout in multi Auth in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I create multi auth (user and admin) in Laravel 5.3, after click on logout, all session expire in Laravel 5.3.

I do not want all session expire after click on logout.

In `Admin/Auth/LoginController`:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard('admin')->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/admin/login');
}
```

In `Site/Auth/LoginController`:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard('user')->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

How do I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to access the guard that pertains to the auth you wish to log out, for instance if you had `Commercial` and `Realestate` users, with associated drivers, and you wished to log someone out of their `Commercial` account, you could do:

```
auth()->guard('commercial')->logout();
```

For example.

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy, I edit this question, How to edit `$request->session()->flush();` and `$request->session()->regenerate();` in `user` and `admin` ?

Comment: HI, Please find more tips.

Comment: @mySun I unfortunately do not have the answers to your question. Go ahead and mark this question as answered and open a new one regarding your new issue.